# How can a planet remain in algae bloom over millions of years?

Tags: xenobiology, climate, flora, climate-change

I've been developing a planet for an original scifi setting and I'm not sure if it's scientifically plausible. Said planet is in a state of global algae infestation across all major oceans, resulting from unchecked industrial activity several million years before the present. The few surviving fauna were either hardy extremophiles or formed a symbiotic relationship with the algae, such as undergoing kleptoplasty. These organisms became the dominant lifeforms, speciating into a relatively diverse ecosystem, albeit not as complex as the previous generation. The ecological shift was long enough ago for a moderately intelligent animal species, comparable to corvids or chimpanzees, to evolve into a sapient one with at least a neolithic level of technology.

My main concern is whether or not this infested state would last long enough for this to occur. Algae blooms on Earth typically only last a few weeks before the algae runs out of sustenance, suggesting a relatively quick recovery. I previously considered increased volcanic activity, another byproduct of global warming, as a new source of greenhouse gases and nitrates. However, I'm not sure if this would be enough to perpetuate the bloom for millions of years.

What mechanism would allow a planet to remain in an algae-infested state for an extended period?

Background info/criteria:

- The planet's physical characteristics differ from Earth, being twice as massive with a 25% larger radius. Its surface gravity is about 28% higher, resulting in flatter terrain and overall smaller landmasses due to heavy erosion. Its rotational period is 43.125 hours, with an axial tilt of 6.2°. It is tidally locked to a mars-sized companion, creating a permanent 800m tidal bulge. As a result, its landmasses are concentrated on opposite hemispheres perpendicular to the companion planet.
- The main causes of the planet's current state include: unchecked greenhouse gas emissions, namely CO2 and methane; rampant fracking and mineral harvest, deep enough into the planet's crust to cause mild instability and increase volcanic activity; excessive use of fertilizer and dumping organic waste, such as sewage.
- Currently, the planet's average surface temperature is about 25°C, 10 degrees hotter than it was before the collapse. There is no surface ice due to a lack of major polar landmasses with high mountains. Tropical regions exceed 30°C, consisting of scorched, barren landmasses and desert archipelagoes. The algal bloom encompasses all bodies of water, including major oceans and smaller inland bodies such as lakes and rivers. The current generation of fauna descended from the few hardy organisms which survived the collapse and mass-deoxygenation. Many of them are kleptoplastic, absorbing the chloroplasts from the algae to undergo photosynthesis and produce their own oxygen. Others are simply adapted to anoxic conditions, including abyssal sea life.
- This state should last at least 10 million years, and the mechanism perpetuating it can't be actively sustained by sapients. The planet's state is the result of sapient actions, *but* they went extinct shortly after the collapse. Whether or not the current sapients can perpetuate the bloom is irrelevant since they've only recently become intellient enough to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @Thoth, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please take a momen to read through our [tour] and the following two Help Center pages ([help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]) to better understand our site. We have rules, one of which is that you can only ask one question per post (multiple questions is a direct reason to close a post, click "close" and read "Needs More Focus").

Comment: In the meantime, it's worth noting that while I find a recession to a planetary algeal bloom plausible, the many-million-year time frame is harder to swallow. In the beginning, the algeal infestation was part of the planet changing from one evironmental and ecological condition to the next. What it changed into is now here, and while we can theoretically create the conditions that would allow algae to form, the planet, itself, on a planetary scale is already where it needs to be to fight  back the infestation. Thus, millions of years are a challenge for me.

Comment: One more thing, if you see that comment from the Community BOT (it's software automation), it means your post is vague enough that the automatics couldn't detect a plausible quesiton. That's a 100% sure sign that you need to [edit] your post and clarify what you're asking for. Please don't ignore the Community BOT.

Comment: @JBH Thank you for the feedback, I will try to reword the question to better clarify what I'm asking about.

Comment: @JBH Does this look better? I tried to include what I'm trying to solve, how it can be executed and what other information I've already researched. As for why I want to get this result, I've put a lot of effort into this setting and I'm hesitant to completely abandon the original premise. I'm not sure if "because I want to" is good enough a reason to include in the question itself.

Comment: @JBH I've posted this question the the Sandbox for feedback, should I delete this post?

Comment: Yes. Now that it's there, we can focus on your specific needs and help you craft good questions.

Comment: Doubt this is possible however, wherever there's excess biomass or edible stuff, eventually someone would learn how to eat it, thus I doubt your condition would last long enough for mind to evolve without some species learning how to eat algae.

Comment: @Vesper Funny you should mention that, at least one species of fauna on this planet is kleptoplastic, eating the algae and absorbing its chloroplasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Dust**

[The Impact Of Saharan Dust On The Occurrence Of Algae Blooms](https://www.witpress.com/elibrary/wit-transactions-on-ecology-and-the-environment/36/5394)

Your algal blooms are fertilized by dust blowing from the wasted land.  Also these oceans are not very deep.  Sometimes they dry up.  Until they fill again, if they do, the dry beds also become a reservoir of dust, blowing to other oceans that are still wet.

The sky is red and tan with dust.  It is a fine contrast with the uniformly green sea.  The sail on my boat is white.  I have left a track behind me in the green sea, and it is dark blue.

Comment: I like this idea quite a lot, it tracks with the planet having a flatter topography and hotter climate, especially towards the equatorial region. I pictured it as a band of scorched desert islands and small, dry continents with average temperatures exceeding 30°C. As a side note, the algae and plantlife on this planet is actually reddish since it orbits a K5V star. I'm imagining a monochromatic landscape of rusty skies over a burgundy ocean, dotted with light red islands.

Comment: Would it be possible for this dust to be mostly localized at the equator, fuelling the rest of the oceans by circulating to higher latitudes?

Comment: @Thoth - that is pretty much what is going on with our planet.  The dust fueling European algae is coming from the Sahara.  If your dust was coming from dead oceans or farmlands turning to desert it would be richer as regards nitrogen and phosphorus.

Comment: Your algal bloom is burgundy?  That reminds me of the ochre growth that occupies the dry seabeds of Barsoom.

Comment: The plants on this planet use phycoethryn as their primary photosynthetic chemical, as the local starlight peaks in the red rather than green. This is the opposite of how Earth plants use phycoethryn to absorb as much blue light as possible in the deep ocean.

Comment: Apologies for updating this question after you originally answered it. I meant to delete it shortly after it was flagged by the bot, as I moved it over to the Sandbox for refinement, but I left it open. Your answer still meets the criteria I'm looking for with the current wording. Again, sorry for any confusion.